# Which OpenGL implementation is best for Java

Tags: java, opengl, 3d

Im about to start a small project using OpenGL and Java. Looking through this website and google it seems to be unclear what implenetation of OpenGL is best to be used within Java.

I've obtained this list from: [Open GL](http://www.opengl.org/resources/bindings/)

- The JOGL Java/OpenGL bindings
- Java 3D (SUN's retained mode library layered on OpenGL)
- OpenGL for Java (GL4Java)
- YAJOGLB (Yet Another Java OpenGL Binding)
- jGL: a 3D graphics library for the Java

What would use recommend in terms of the amount of resources aviabale to learn it and simpleness of implementing a simple either car,helicopter or flight simulator in?

Comment: I removed the homework flag. The tag is obsolete and should not be used anymore. But instead of using the flag I would still recommend you to mention that the question is about homework, so that people know that you want to learn and not just need a quick solution for the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just a beginner with OpenGL but I've been using LWJGL (http://www.lwjgl.org/), which Minecraft uses.

If you want something more high level, try an engine like jMonkeyEngine (http://jmonkeyengine.com/).

Comment: JMonkeyEngine builds on top of LWJGL as far as I know. More frameworks and engines do that, like LibGDX and Slick.

Comment: I have started using LWJGL and finding it very nice so far.. could you update your post with reccommend resources that you found useful? Im currently using youtube videos.. And jmonkey was to high level :)

Answer (score 1):

I would advise to look into LibGDX if I were you. LWJGL and JOGL are targeted towards PC games. LibGDX on the other hand targets computers with the help of LWJGL, but also Android and iOS; to top it off it supports "HTML 5" with the help of Google Web Toolkit (GWT) - all through a generic API.